# On upgrade from 13 to 14, wifi no longer works

Tags: wireless, networking, upgrade

I had Ubuntu 13 and wifi worked great.  I just upgraded to 14.04.  The wifi no longer works.  Wired networking works great.  I have put the output of wireless_script in http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7935765 .

In particular I noticed this.

```
ftpmaint@millstone:~/tmp/wifi$ rfkill list
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
ftpmaint@millstone:~/tmp/wifi$
```

Maybe I misunderstand this entirely, but I certainly did not open the box and disable anything.

It is a Dell Latitude E6330 (it was listed as "precertified" for 12.04 so I thought that would likely mminimize incompatibiliteis), with Intel 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection.

I'd be very grateful for any help.

Jim

Comment: Does your laptop have a button or switch for turning on and off your wireless card?

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing.  I never knew there was a switch but I guess that I must have somehow hit it during the time I was updating and the update was a misdirection.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm going to post as answer so it might help others.

Answer (score 1):

Hard block usually means the wireless card is turned off, usually by a key combination on the keyboard or a physical switch. Make sure you have wireless enabled and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Just so no one spends any time on the problem: ElefantPhace asked me about a switch that I had somehow knocked, and that proved to be the solution.  Thanks so much; hope I can somehow return the help.